# how to use Redis Server Detection in laravel?

Tags: socket.io, laravel-5.1

1-Xampp

2-laravel 5.1

3-run localhost:8000

class in function

```
$redis = LRedis::connection();
$redis->publish('message', "fgfgff");
```

error
ConnectionException in AbstractConnection.php line 155:
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it. [tcp://127.0.0.1:6379]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to create a connection between 2 host Redis is not an answer for you.
check out this question about what is Redis:
[What is Redis and what do I use it for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888880/what-is-redis-and-what-do-i-use-it-for)

The problem with the Connection is probably because of the URL sending to the client side socket constructor.

change : var socket = io('http://localhost');

to : var socket = io();

Here is a link on step by step guide to use socket.io:

search "use socket.io with laravel" in Google.

To use connection between 2 host with Laravel you should use a package as it is not in Laravel by default.
this package enables push notification between server and devices like android or ios phones. here is the link to the package in GitHub:
[davibennun/laravel-push-notification](https://github.com/davibennun/laravel-push-notification)

Hope to be useful.
good luck.